# PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have such entity:

```
public class Foo {

  private long id;
  private List<Bar> list = new ArrayList<>();

  public long getId() {
     return id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
     this.id = id;
  }

  public List<Bar> getList() {
     return list;
  }

  public void setList(List<Bar> list) {
     this.list = list;
  }

  /** helper method*/
  public boolean isEmpty(){
     return list.isEmpty();
  }
}
```

And corresponding entity mapping:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                     version="2.1">

    <entity class="Foo">
     <table name="foo"/>
     <attributes>
       <id name="id"/>
        <one-to-many name="list">
          <!-- ... -->
        </one-to-many>
        <transient name="isEmpty"/>
     </attributes>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

And this exception I got:`org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate setter method for property [Foo#empty]`
I found a similar post - [HIbernate Mapping Exception: PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032260/hibernate-mapping-exception-propertynotfoundexception-could-not-find-a-setter) and there Trainsient annotation on such method helped.

Comment: You should be able to make Hibernate ignore your method by simply not including it at all in the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying `<transient name="isEmpty"/>` you try to signal to the JPA provider that you have a transient property named `isEmpty`. Your property is actually named `empty`, not `isEmpty`, and the error message indicates that too (`Foo#empty`). Replace the corresponding XML tag with `<transient name="empty"/>`.